# jQuery replace text and format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this text in some places of my site:

```
<a class="classCover"> 1: Comentario: </a>
```

And I would like to reformat it to:

```
<a class="classCover"> Comentarios: 1 </a>
```

Any idea to remove dots and reorder this text taking into account that the number will be dinamic depending on the numbers of comments? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `str.replace('1: Comentario:', 'Comentarios: 1')` ?

Comment: @adeneo Not always since the number will be dinamic depending on the number of comments

Comment: @Antonio Is there only one element with that class or multiple?

Comment: @Tushar Multiple, will be a dinamic number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
text.split(':').reverse().join(':');
```

1. `trim` the leading and trailing whitespaces
2. Remove the leading and trailing `:`
3. Split the text by `:`
4. Reverse the array
5. Join the text by `:`

```js
$('.classCover').text(function(e, oldText) {
  return oldText.trim().replace(/^:|:$/g, '').split(':').reverse().join(':');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="classCover"> 1: Comentario: </a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, always learning with person like you. Anyway, how can I apply the 's' to the final of word to have: Comentarios: 1?

Comment: By using `.replace('Comentario', 'Comentarios')`.on the string

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
$(document).on('click', '.classOver',function(e){
     $(this).text('Comentarios: 1');
});
```